# Who was the swift woman from from Irish Mythology described as having backward knees?

Tags: myth-identification, irish, ulster-cycle

This [question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/2896/57) got me thinking about the Irish depiction of legs in mythology.

- I remember one woman, in particular, from (I believe) the Ulster Cycle, described as having backward legs, similar to a stag or horse, to connote her inhuman swiftness. (The Greek heroine [Atalanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atalanta#Footrace) is one parallel, although I can no longer remember the gist of the Irish story.)

---

*Not strictly related: [Cut Across Shorty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvzZlajPVAo)*

Comment: This detail might possibly occur in some tellings of the story of Macha's foot-race, reckoned among the *remscela* of the *Táin* in that it explains the curse by which the Ulstermen suffer disabling pangs as of childbirth in their hour of most need. I don't recall it, however, from [Kinsella's version](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-tain-9780192803733?cc=us&lang=en&) (pp. 6–8), for which the source text for this *remscel* is that edited by Windisch and published in 1884.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Good call re: [Macha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macha).  The the Kinsella is my favorite translation, but I'm not entirely sure if the description of the reverse legs derives from the Táin or the broader Ulster cycle.

Comment: Note the association with horses in the Wiki piece you link.

Comment: Didn't the Badb Catha have backwards knees (along with other grotesque features) in Togail Bruidne Dá Derga?

Comment: For what it's worth, horses (dogs, etc.) don't actually have "backward knees".  They have short thighs and very long feet, making their heels look like backward knees.